# make grub messages remain visible

Tags: grub2

Is there anything I can do to make grub messages stay visible long enough for me to read them?

In particular, is there a way to change the grub interface from the (apparently) character mode graphics to something more like a teletype?

In the time between the Dell logo and the grub menu, I can see messages flash on the screen, but they're not there long enough for me to read them, let alone long enough for me to understand them.

I tried echo statements in the grub configuration file (grub.cfg), thinking they would show up in the middle of the menu.  They didn't.

I've had some luck with putting echo statements in a menu item, before the kernel load command.  The "read" statement isn't allowed in UEFI Secure Boot, but it does delay grub long enough for me to read some of what I've written.  What I haven't found any way to do is to read the error messages that flash up just before the menu is displayed.

Comment: You have a "pause" button on your keyboard ;)

Comment: I do not have a "pause" button on my keyboard.  No Break or SysReq.  I also do not have the reflexes needed to catch these messages as they flicker by.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sleep -i 1000
```

will pause for 1000 seconds.  It can be interrupted by hitting ESCAPE.

I once managed to hit the Shift key at the right times during the BIOS boot to get a peek at the single message that comes out of `shim` (shimx64.efi?).  I can't reproduce it.  I think it starts with holding the Shift key down while the DELL logo is displayed, until an empty progress bar pops up at the bottom of the screen.  Releasing the Shift key causes the boot to resume.  I assume I hit the Shift key again just as it filled, but I'm not sure.